# 2 vectors in $\mathbb{K}^2$ are linear independent if and only if $ad−bc≠0 $

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following assignment what I've also posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657147/are-the-proofs-i-made-correct/657164?noredirect=1#comment1383019_657164) but the proof I provided there was wrong. I am no sure whether opening a new thread for that is allowed - I will definitely link to this one in the other post.

Note: I am not allowed to use determinants in my solution.

Now the assignment:
Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{K}$ and $v_i \in \mathbb{K}$ for $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove or falsify the following statements about linear independency:

Let $v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}, ~ v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} c \\ d \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{K}^2$. $(v_1, v_2)$ are linear independent if and only if ad−bc≠0

### My approach

Let $w$ and $v$ be linear independent. Thus one could write:

$\lambda_1(a+b) + \lambda_2(c+d) = 0$

Now lets say $ad-bc = 0 \Leftrightarrow ad = bc$

Furthermore one could write:

$$a+b = \frac{d}{d}a + \frac{c}{c}b = \frac{bc}{d} + \frac{bc}{c} = bc\left(\frac{1}{d}+\frac{1}{c}\right) = ad\left(\frac{1}{d}+\frac{1}{c}\right)$$

$$c+d = \frac{b}{b}c + \frac{a}{a}d = \frac{ad}{b} + \frac{ad}{a} = ad\left(\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{a}\right)$$

Thus we get:

$$\lambda_1(a+b) + \lambda_2(c+d) = \lambda_1  ad\left(\frac{1}{d}+\frac{1}{c}\right) + \lambda_2 ad\left(\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{a}\right) = ad\left[\lambda_1  \left(\frac{1}{d}+\frac{1}{c}\right)   + \lambda_2 \left(\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{a}\right)\right]$$

There we get that the trivial solution is not $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = 0$ but $ac = 0$ and the vectors are not linear independent anymore - **contradiction**.

Can one do that?

Thank you very much!

FunkyPeanut

Comment: $v_1=(a,b)$ and $v_2=(c,d)$?

Comment: Yes - omg sorry.

Comment: $v_1,v_2$ are l.i. iff  det(matrix with columns $v_1,v_2$)=0

Comment: I am not allowed to use determinants in this assignment - I should add that in my post.

Comment: If $d=0$ your are not allowed to use $d/d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(a,b)=(0,0)$ or $(c,d)=(0,0)$ we're done.  So we assume $a\neq0$ and $c\neq0$. We will prove: $\begin{pmatrix}a\\ b\end{pmatrix}\parallel\begin{pmatrix}c\\ d\end{pmatrix}\iff ad=bc$. Iff both vectors are parallel there exists $k\in K$ such that $ka-c=0$ and $kb-d=0$; this $k$ can't be $0$, otherwise $c=d=0$. By multiplying the first equation by $d$, the second by $-c$ and adding both equation we arrive in $k(ad-bc)=0$.

If conversely $ad-bc=0$, suppose that $a=0$. Then $b\neq0$, thus $c=0$ and $d\neq0$ so $k=d/b$, similar if $b=0$. Now if $a\neq0$ and $b\neq0$, choose $k=c/a$.